# How can I return a list in __repr__ function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class Menu

```
class Menu:

    options = []
    label = 'empty'

    def __init__(self, label, options):
        self.label = label
        self.options = options

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s \n=====================\n\n%s' % (self.label, self.options[0])
```

What I am trying to do here is format the repr function so that it prints all the options. Right now it will correctly print

```
Label

\==============

Option 1
```

But can I throw a for loop in that return statement, or is there a proper way of fixing this?

Comment: `menu_options = ` is not valid Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can join all the values in the list, with [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) function and return it like this

```
return "{}\n=======\n\nOptions :[{}]".format(self.label, ", ".join(self.options))
```

**Note:**

1. If you are creating an attribute called `options` in `__init__`, it will shadow the class level attribute `options`, when you access it with `self`.
2. `self.options = options` will not create a new list when you assign. It will make both `self.options` and `options` refer the same list object passed. So, if you change `self.options`, it will be reflected in `options` as well. If you want to make a copy, you can use slicing like this `self.options = options[:]`

Comment: What is the main difference between the %s approach and the .format approach ?

And yes I'll need to look into how classes actually work

Comment: @Thustra You might want to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5082452/1903116) to know more about `format` and `%` syntax differences.

Comment: I'll accept it

I went with this for now to create the options list, to add some numbers.

`option_list = '\n'.join([str(self.options.index(option) + 1) + '. ' + option for option in self.options])`

And then I give that as the second parameter for format()